# Manipulation of a tkinter image: why does it run more than 10 times faster when manipulating the picture before it is placed on the canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When I was working on my tkinter application, I stumbled upon the following phenomenon. I was experimenting with changing colors on a tk.PhotoImage object. Here is the code: for each pixel it picks the color value and changes it to black or white (it doesn't matter, just an example).

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

picture = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'image.png')
cnv = tk.Canvas(width=800, height=600)
cnv.pack()
cnv.create_image(0,0, anchor=tk.NW, image=picture)   # create_image here: > 35 seconds
for px in range(800):
    for py in range(600):
        color = picture.get(px,py)
        newcolor = '#ffffff' if color[0] > 128 else '#000000'
        picture.put(newcolor, (px,py))

# cnv.create_image(0,0, anchor=tk.NW, image=picture)   # create_image here: ~ 3 seconds
tk.mainloop()
```

When you run this code, really, have some patience, it takes over 35 seconds (on an iCore7) before the window finally pops up. But it will.

Now, when I create the canvas image *after* I changed all the colors, the code runs more than 10 times faster ! The lack (in both cases) is caused by the `put()` function (the `get()` function is fast).

What is happening beneath the surface that explains this huge difference?

**Sample picture (any 800x600 PNG will do)**

[image: sample picture]

Comment: my guess would be that if you create the canvas beforehand, changing every pixel triggers something internally that has to go and re-draw the image onto the canvas. Doing it after means you'd only be drawing the image to the canvas once.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but since the picture isn't displayed until it finished anyway, I wasn't so sure anymore.

Comment: Why don't consider to use `Pillow` module to handle the picture?

Comment: Because the question is not about 'how to speed up', it is about the inner workings of tkinter and the tkinter canvas.

Comment: I couldn't help anymore.You may could find it [in the source code of `tk`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/dir?ci=tip).